# How do I know what is the cause of external code being called in Visual Studio CPU profiler?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, profiler

I did profiling of my asp.net web application when it randomly started using 99% of CPU to know what is going on. But what I get is some `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,int>.FindEntry(int)` called by some other external code are the most expensive one. [image: lowest part of call tree]

What can I do with this information? It *should* be somehow related to my code (or at least my actions), but profiler is showing me just that some external code are calling other external code (which I can neither look at, let alone change).

**How do I know what is the cause of this? Is it even possible?**

This is the other parts of call stack (from top to bottom, and the bottomest is `FindEntry` method), if it is somehow useful:[image: uppermost part]

[image: part below]

[image: and below]

Comment: For information about "Measure application performance by analyzing CPU usage", you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I got this same problem.  I tried turning on native and external code debugging and that helped but it's still very confusing.  It seems like VS profiler has a hard time tying external codes calls back to whatever ultimate started the call chain in your own code.